# Error with AJAX, requesting a file from my local machine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to load a section of html into my site, but i'm getting this error:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've seen this error before but only when trying to request files on a different server. I'm loading a local file in the same directory as the page that's requesting it, so i'm not sure why i'm receiving this error.

Here's the javascript i'm using to request it

```
$('#page').load('homepage.html')
```

Comment: Are you using the `file://` protocol? Install a web server instead.

Comment: Maybe try putting the absolute url in the `.load` like `.load("http://localhost/homepage.html");`

Comment: is it a some mobile javascript you are using to load the page. Check you html page contents

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that @JasonP hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Yup, @JasonP nailed it. I'm on a brand new computer and totally forgot to set up a web server before I started working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading "homepage/html"?

The error you are getting means *either* the protocol is different

ie: you are using

```
file://foo/bar/whatever_has_your_js_script.html
```

but you really want

```
 http://...
```

OR the host is different. Sound like this is not the case

In my experience, for work on a local machine, I "accidentally" open an html *as* a file, instead of by localhost/http. For example:

```
file://localhost/foo/mySpace/blog.html
```

would cause an error trying to get an ajax call, but

```
http://localhost/foo/mySpace/blog.html
```

might not. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy